# Обновление html после отправки ajax-формы

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, веб-программирование

Мне нужен совет, как правильно обновлять html после отправки ajax запроса.
Предположим есть обычная страница с комментариями. На сервере при запросе странице идет запрос в базу на получение всех комментариев. Грубый пример:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE page_id = 2");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
  while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $render . = "<div class="comment-row"><h3>{$data['author']}</h3><p>{$data['message']}</p></div>"
  }
  echo $render;
}
```

Таким образом происходит начальная отрисовка страницы. Есть форма отправки комментария, которая отправляется посредством ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'comment.php',
  data: data, //здесь данные из формы собранные с помощью FormData();
  type: 'post',
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
}).done(function (data){
  ... //делаем что-то с отрисовкой.
});
```

На сервере эти данные отлавливаются, данные кладутся в базу и вот вопрос, а как правильно обновлять html после добавления? Самый банальный вариант, просто оставить простую форму без ajax, но хочется динамики.
**Вариант 1:**
На сервере кладем в базу инфу и после успешной процедуры возвращаем json параметров, которые только что были отправлены формой:
*test.php*

```
...
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO Comments (author, message) VALUES ('{$_POST['author']}', '{$_POST['message']}')");
exit(json_encode([$_POST['author'], $_POST['message']]));
```

*клиент*

```
...//ajax
.done(function (data){
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  let firstComment = $('.comment-row:first');
  firstComment.before(`<div class="comment-row"><h3>${data.author}</h3><p>${data.message}</p></div>`);
});
```

Таким образом мы вроде как не генерируем лишний html код на сервере, а перекладываем все это дело на клиента освобождая сервер.
**Вариант 2:**
Примерно тоже самое, но вместо отдачи json мы отдаем готовый html нового поста с комментом.
*test.php*

```
...
$data = "<div class="comment-row"><h3>{$_POST['author']}</h3><p>{$_POST['messge']}</p></div>";
exit($data);
```

*Клиент*

```
...
.done(function (data){
  $('.comment-row:first').before(data);
});
```

**Вариант 3:**
Не паримся и просто запрашиваем все комменты из бд и отдаем их целиком:
*test.php*

```
... //выбираем из бд все комменты после вставки нового
$comments = '';
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $comments .= "<div class=\"comment-row\"><h3>{$data['author']}</h3><p>{$data['message']}</p></div>"
}
exit($comments);
```

*Клиент*

```
...
$('#container-comments').html(data);
```

**Вариант 4**
Совершенно не паримся и просто перезагружаем страницу. После перезагрузки изначальным скриптом мы получим все комменты, однако зачем тогда вообще ajax?

Собственно какой вариант сейчас применяется и является наиболее правильным? Возможно я что-то упускаю и есть более лучшее решение?
*Весь код написан сугубо для примера и общей наглядности, поэтому в нем нет никаких проверок входящих данных на SQL-инъекции и другие уязвимости в пользу краткости изложения примера.*

UPD: Проект в рамках которого задается вопрос, представляет собой подобие соцсети, с возможностью размещения объявлений, создания групп (подобие групп ВК), наличием профиля пользователя с включенным в него возможностью создания фотоальбомов, хранилища документов и возможностью обмениваться личными сообщениями между зарегистрированными участниками. (Относительно вопроса про комменты - комменты можно оставлять в объявлениях, группах и других подобных фукнционалах проекта, при чем к комментам предполагается прикрепление фото или документов. Исходя из этого помимо комментов с ajax отправкой формы, точно также может быть реализованы добавление новых объявлений/групп/записей/сообщений).

Comment: Вариант 1 очень хорош. Приближен к идеалу, с точки зрения SPA. Если хотите работать с `ajax`, рекомендую почитать что такое `REST`.

Comment: А что бы вам не дублировать код, который создает html разметку коммента, надо все комменты также запрашивать через ajax.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Спасибо за ответ! Но можно чуть поподробнее? Я понимаю с точки зрения работы с php, что изначальный контент отдается сервером, как я показал в начале вопроса, но как это сделать запросом через ajax и для чего нужен REST? Насколько я знаю с помощью REST пишут API обращаясь к разным роутам. Вы имеете ввиду сделать веб-приложения по типу REST, где на каждый запрос будет отдавать тот самый JSON пакет данных, который уже будет применен JSом для генерации верстки? Эдакий первый вариант из вопроса, но глобальный.

Comment: В принципе вы правы, да. Я тут подумал, что сложно дать объективный ответ раках всего проекта. В рамках вашего вопроса Вариант 1 хорош. Но и у Варианта 2 есть преимущество в плане отсутствия дублирования кода. Можете дополнить вопрос с информацией о проекте: для чего он, на какой стадии, какие технологии используются. Тогда можно будет дать долее объективный ответ.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

На странице сохраняем время когда мы последний раз обновляли данные.

На сервере реализуем метод, возвращающий массив сообщений, которые были созданы или обновлены после запрошенного времени.

Этот метод можно вызывать по таймеру и обязательно после отправки/изменения своего сообщения.

Comment: Не подскажете, каким образом хранить время обновления на странице? Для нескольких блоков подобного рода (если допустим есть не только комментарии) необходимо будет хранить несколько меток времени?  

И если вызывать подобный метод по таймеру, он неизбежно раз в несколько секунд (зависит от таймера) долбить запросами сервер и в частности БД на предмет обновления. На мой взгляд это не очень хорошо. Поправьте, если я не прав.

Comment: Насчет таймера - согласен, сейчас есть и другие методы.
Хранить время можно как в скрытом поле той же формы, которой отправляете сам текст, так и просто в переменной JavaScript'а